# How do you set the HTML font size in graphviz?

Tags: html, fonts, graphviz

Graphviz allows labels to be specified via "HTML-Like labels", as shown e.g. in section 2.3 of the [Drawing graphs with dot](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf) User's Guide.

That gives examples of how to change the font color, but specifying

```
<FONT SIZE="8">text</FONT>
```

results in an error message

```
Warning: Illegal attribute SIZE in <FONT> - ignored
```

How can the font size of "HTML-Like" labels be manipulated?

Answer (score 14):

The term "HTML-Like labels" reflects the fact that a full HTML implementation is not included, and the syntax varies from HTML at times.  For details see the documentation on [Node Shapes | Graphviz - Graph Visualization Software](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html).

There you will see that font sizes can be specified via the "POINT-SIZE" attribute.  E.g.

```
 <FONT POINT-SIZE="8">text</FONT>
```